# error con MySQL : Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

hace unos dias comenze a trabajar con las bases de datos de MySQL en mi servidor local, por el momento iba bien hasta que añadi la variable de usuario, solo lo habia hecho con email pero con usuario no, ahora cuando añadi esa variable me salta el error de

> "Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\2018\Registro2\signup.php on line 11"

y ya analice mi codigo y no encuentro el problema, mi codigo de signup.php es

```
<?php 
    require 'database.php';
    $message = '';
    if (!empty($_POST['usuario']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, email, password) VALUES (:usuario, :email, :password)";
        $stmt = $conn -> prepare($sql);
        $stmt -> bindParam(':usuario',$_POST['usuario']);
        $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        $stmt -> bindParam(':password',$_POST['password']);

        if ($stmt -> execute()) {
            $message = 'Se ha creado su cuenta satisfactoriamente en la pagina';
        }
        else {
            $message = 'Lo sentimos, pero ha ocurrido un problema con la base de datos';
        }
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Registrarse</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php require 'partials/header.php' ?>
    <?php if (!empty($message)):
    ?>
        <p><?= $message ?></p>
    <?php
    endif; 
    ?>
    <h1>Registrarse</h1>
    <span>ó <a href="login.php">Iniciar Sesión</a></span>
    <form action="signup.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña">
        <input type="password" name="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirme la contraseña">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

y el database.php es este:

```
<?php
$server = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'usuarios';
try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database;", $username, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  die('Connection Failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

Comment: Mi buen amigo el mismo numero de columnas en tu table deben ser las mismas que registres, como dice el amigo Alfredo Paz te falta la variable de email, la esta solicitando en tu consulta de mysql pero no la estas pasando en tus variables. Quitala del inserte o bie agregala en tus post. Saludos

Comment: gracias, creo que puede ser eso, voy a intentarlo, gracias a los 2

Comment: Que bueni que ya te salio amigo, saludos

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> El numero de valores que le mandes en forma de variables se debe
>   corresponder al número de columnas que planeas llenar en tu tabla de
>   tu base de datos, cosa que no ocurre pues te hace falta el atributo
>   `mail`
>
> Es por eso que te indica que el número de tokens no empata, por que el
>   número de variables no se corresponde con el número de columnas

**FINALMENTE CON LOS COMENTARIOS QUE TE HAGO, TU CÓDIGO DEBERÍA QUEDAR DEL MODO SIGUIENTE**

```
<?php 
    require 'database.php';
    $message = '';
    if (!empty($_POST['usuario']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, email, password) VALUES (:usuario, :email, :password)";
        $stmt = $conn -> prepare($sql);
        $stmt -> bindParam(':usuario',$_POST['usuario']);
        $stmt -> bindParam(':email',$_POST['email']);
        $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
        $stmt -> bindParam(':password',$_POST['password']);

        if ($stmt -> execute()) {
            $message = 'Se ha creado su cuenta satisfactoriamente en la pagina';
        }
        else {
            $message = 'Lo sentimos, pero ha ocurrido un problema con la base de datos';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, voy a intentar a ver si me funciona, gracias

Comment: por favor regresas y comentas si sirvió o no

Comment: lo acabo de revisar y si me funciono, muchisimas gracias

Comment: creo que ya, cierto, soy nuevo en stack, al parecer  no puedo puntuar aun por mi reputacion

Comment: gracias, te tendre en cuenta

Answer (score 0):

claro al momento que ejecutas la inserción pones los parámetros y después pon los valores tal y cual están escritos.
Aquí te dejo un código de  ejemplo:

```php
if($accion!=''){
    switch($accion){

        case 'agregar':

            $sql="INSERT INTO cursos(id, nombre_curso) VALUES (NULL,:nombre_curso)";
            $consulta=$conexionBD->prepare($sql);
            $consulta->bindParam(':nombre_curso',$nombre_curso);
            $consulta->execute();

            echo $sql;
            break;
        case 'editar':
            $sql="UPDATE `cursos` SET (nombre_curso='$nombre_curso' WHERE id=$id)";
            // $sql="UPDATE `cursos` SET nombre_curso='$nombre_curso' WHERE `id`=$id";
            echo $sql;
            break;
        case 'borrar':
            $sql="DELETE FROM `cursos` WHERE id=$id";
            echo $sql;
            break;
    }

}
```

[image: Algo asi]