# Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens; pagina web

Tags: php, html, mysql

Quiero crear una página web, en la que ingresar un usuario y contraseña y eso me lleva a otra página, pero cuando ingreso mis datos de la tabla mysql no me lleva a la pagina que quiero y me aparece este error

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\web02\paginas\conexion.php:43 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\web02\paginas\conexion.php(43): PDOStatement->execute() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\web02\paginas\proceso.php(13): Conexion->LoginAccess('jgodoy', '123') #2 {main} thrown in **C:\xampp\htdocs\web02\paginas\conexion.php** on line **43**

Mi tabla/base de datos de mysql esta correcto asi que el problema esta en el codigo pero no logro hallarlo

Mi codigo proceso.php **linea 13**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["btnlogin"])) {

    // print_r($_POST);

    $user = $_POST["txtuser"];
    $psw = $_POST["txtpsw"];

    include("conexion.php");

    $cn = new Conexion();

    $nr = $cn->LoginAccess($user, $psw); //linea13

    // echo $nr;

    if ($nr == 1)
        header("location: listado.php");
    else
        header("location: error.php");
    
    }
?>
```

Mi codigo de conexion.php **linea 43**

```
<?php

// Crear la clase conexion
    class Conexion {
    // Definir atributos para la conexión
        private $usuario="root";
        private $password="";
        private $servidor="localhost";
        private $base="sales";

        // Crea un método
        public function Conectar() {
            // Iniciar el controlador de errores
            // Para capturar los posibles errores dentro del código
            // PDO

            // Código a evaluar para posibles errores que pueda existir
            try {
                $con = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->servidor; dbname=$this->base;", $this->usuario,$this->password);
                $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                // echo "Base de datos conectada...";
                return $con;

            // muestra los errores encontrados dentro del código
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo "Se encontró un error: ". $e->getMesagge();
            }
        }

        // Método para validar el acceso de usuario
        public function LoginAccess($user, $psw) {
            $arr_filas = null;

            $cn = $this->Conectar();

             $sql = "select * from userm where userm=: and passw=:psw";

            $rs = $cn->prepare($sql);

            $rs->bindParam(":user", $user);
            $rs->bindParam(":psw", $psw);

            $rs->execute(); //linea 43

            $nr = $rs->rowCount();

            $cn = null;

            return $nr;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/142002/error-con-mysql-invalid-parameter-number-number-of-bound-variables-does-not-m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la línea 36 de tu código tienes incompletos los datos, te hace falta colocar la variable **user** en tu sentencia sql. Por eso durante el **execute()** te manda el error "Invalid parameter number" (Número de parámetro no válido).

Código Original:

```
$sql = "select * from userm where userm=: and passw=:psw";
```

Código Corregido:

```
$sql = "select * from userm where userm=:user and passw=:psw";
```

Intenta corregirlo, si aún así no funciona porfavor me comentas para ver si puedo ayudarte con algo más.

Comment: Gracias, lo puse y me funciono mi codigo muchas gracias enserio